# Is it required to use spin_lock inside tasklets?

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module, spinlock, isr

As far as I know in interrupt handler, there is no need of synchronization technique. The interrupt handler cannot run concurrently. In short, the pre-emption is disabled in ISR. However, I have a doubt regarding tasklets. As per my knowledge, tasklets runs under interrupt context. Thus, In my opinion, there is no need for spin lock under tasklet function routine. However, I am not sure on it. Can somebody please explain on it? Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data is shared between top half and bottom half then go for lock.  Simple rules for locking. Locks meant to protect data not code.

```
1. What to protect?. 
2. Why to protect? 
3. How to protect.
```

Answer (score 1):

Two tasklets of the same type do not ever run simultaneously. Thus, there is no need to protect data used only within a single type of tasklet. If the data is shared between two different tasklets, however, you must obtain a normal spin lock before accessing the data in the bottom half. You do not need to disable bottom halves because a tasklet never preempts another running tasklet on the same processor.

Answer (score 0):

For synchronization between code running in process context (A) and code running in softirq context (B) we need to use special locking primitives. We must use spinlock operations augmented with deactivation of bottom-half handlers on the current processor in (A), and in (B) only basic spinlock operations. Using spinlocks makes sure that we don't have races between multiple CPUs while deactivating the softirqs makes sure that we don't deadlock in the softirq is scheduled on the same CPU where we already acquired a spinlock. (c) Kernel docs